# How can I provide a 1 minute preview of a live flash video stream using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-streaming, jwplayer

I have a site that is streaming live videos, and I want to offer a one minute free preview to users before they pay for a stream.  I am using JW Player - I was thinking of triggering a timer when the play button is clicked, and then removing a div containing the player once the timer is finished.  I am already using jQuery on this page.

What methods can I take to secure this?  Is there another way to do this - I am using a CDN so server-side is somewhat limited.

Comment: Make sure you kill the sound too ;-)

Comment: Great stuff so far. To clarify, I accept that this isn't going to be secure - Pulling out a 1 minute sample video might be a good option in the long term, but in the meantime I need a JS only solution (or maybe something light on the serverside that can mask the real RTMP address).  At the moment the stream is over RTMP being delivered by simpleCDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **not possible** to build a secure 60-seconds-only preview of the full video that way; the only way to be sure that no one could exploit the javascript code and see the entire video is to create a separate video file of 60 seconds only and to play that one instead of the real full video.

This is so because the javascript code is run on the client and it would be pretty easy to disable, edit it or, even simpler, to spot the URL of the full version of the video in the code.

Moreover it's better to protect the download of the full video file checking that every HTTP request made to download it corresponds to a user who has paid for it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using proper streaming (eg RTMP), the whole file will be accessible for direct download by users with access to this pseudo-preview. To properly limit access, you'll want to either implement streaming and limit the free stream server side, or use a one minute file and a protected full video.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I used JW Player's events to fire a setTimeout call for 60 seconds later.  I then hid the player and popped up a modal jQuery UI dialog over the screen.  It's not particularly secure but is sufficient for my needs.